# QMainWindow Open File dialog cut off and doesn't respond

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qt5

My open file dialog in Qt5 is being cut off and it doesn't respond to any mouse clicks. I'm using an OpenGLWindow (per http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtgui-openglwindow-example.html) inside the central widget of the QMainWindow (per http://blog.qt.io/blog/2013/02/19/introducing-qwidgetcreatewindowcontainer/). If I don't set the central widget to my OpenGLWindow, then the open file dialog works, but once I use the OpenGLWindow in the central widget, then this problem occurs. See the screenshot below. Any ideas on how to fix this or debug it?

main.cpp:

```
    ...
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QSurfaceFormat format;
    format.setSamples(16);
    MainWindow mainWin;
    MyOpenGLWindow window();
    window.setFormat(format);
    window.setAnimating(true);

    QWidget *container = QWidget::createWindowContainer(&window);
    mainWin.setCentralWidget(container);

#if defined(Q_OS_SYMBIAN)
    mainWin.showMaximized();
#else
    mainWin.show();
#endif
....
```

mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QFileDialog>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_actionOpen_File_triggered()
{
    QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Open File"), "/home");
}
```

mainwindow.h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
private slots:
    void on_actionOpen_File_triggered();
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.ui:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget"/>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>800</width>
     <height>25</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <widget class="QMenu" name="menuTest_Window">
    <property name="title">
     <string>File</string>
    </property>
    <addaction name="actionOpen_File"/>
   </widget>
   <addaction name="menuTest_Window"/>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
  <action name="actionOpen_File">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Open File</string>
   </property>
  </action>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

[image: Open File dialog cut off]

Comment: Did you try not using the `parent`, e.g. `QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(nullptr, tr("Open File"), "/home");`?

Comment: @Zeta, I had not tried that, but trying it now, it doesn't work. Still the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the way to solve this is to use an [QOpenGLWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglwidget.html) (per https://blog.qt.io/blog/2014/09/10/qt-weekly-19-qopenglwidget/). The QWindow approach to using OpenGL doesn't seem to mix well with other QWidgets. I successfully transferred my application to use a QOpenGLWidget now and it works!